# Need column of numbers from file. Each number must then go to another file via find/replace sed. Problem: final files all have same number

Tags: bash, file, awk, replace, io

I am struggling with Bash and Awk scripting, which I have been using to organize many large files. The patient advice here has been very helpful.  I have a new problem.

1. I have many identical files called "input."  They contain numbers and strings.  Directory "Parent" contains daughter directories (Daughter1, Daughter2, Daughter3, and so on).  Each daughter directory contains one "input" file.
2. A separate file, "numbers.txt," only contains one column of numbers. There are as many numbers/rows in the column as there are Parent/Daughter(i)/input files.  Short example:

   ```
   10.987  
   10.654321  
   13.3210
   ```
3. I want to change one number in each input file to a new number from numbers.txt.  The file at Daughter1/input should be changed to the number from the first row of numbers.txt.  Daughter2/input should be changed to the number at the second row of numbers.txt, and so on.

So far, I have found that this sed (it's "gsed" here; I'm an OS X Sierra user) expression below is reliable and I'd like to keep using it if possible:

```
#!/bin/bash

old_number="12.345678" # This number is in all "input" files. 
new_number="87.654321"

find Parent/Daughter* -type f -exec gsed -i -e "s/${old_number}/${new_number}/g" {} +
```

The problem is that I have not been able to modify `${new_number}` in the code above so that it correctly uses numbers from "numbers.txt" (2, above).  Here's something that almost works.  It does change the old number in the "input" files (1, above), but ALL of the input files now contain `10.987` (the first number).  Each input file should have a distinct number.

```
i=0
while read line
do
    arr[$i]="$line"
    find Parent/Daughter* -type f -exec gsed -i -e "s/${old_number}/${arr[i]}/g" {} +
    i=$((i+1))
done < numbers.txt
```

If this question is too long or unclear, I would be happy to modify it.  Thank you.

---

**Update** 
jas's suggestion (see comments below my question) gets me most of the way there. Thank you, jas!  I need to figure out how to identify the number of Parent/Daughter/input files I have and stop the loop when I get to the last one, but other than that, this is working well.

```
i=0
while read line
do
    arr[$i]="$line"
    find Parent/Daughter${i} -type f -exec gsed -i -e "s/${old_number}/${arr[i]}/g" {} +
    i=$((i+1))
done < numbers.txt
```

Comment: The problem is that you're modifying all of the files returned by `find` the first time through the loop. Instead  of using find, try just running sed on the one file you care  about that time through the loop (`Parent/Daughter${i}/input`, if I understand correctly).

Comment: @jas, it's almost working.  If you want to add an answer, I will mark it correct.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since each time through the loop you only want to update one file, and you know exactly which file that is, you can run the sed directly without needing find. (Also, I think there's no need to use the array variable, unless you need it for something later):

```
i=1
while read line
do
    gsed -i -e "s/${old_number}/${line}/g" Daughter${i}/input
    i=$((i+1))
done < numbers.txt
```

This assumes you have all and only as many lines in the numbers.txt file that you want to use for updating the Daughter*/input files.

Answer (score 0):

*"There are as many number/rows in the column as there are Parent/Daughteri/input files"*

If you have two ordered arrays of the same length then you could use an index to iterate over them. You could generate a list of the input files to be targeted, putting the list of files into an array (array1) that contains the full directory structure of each input file, then iterate over the second array created from numbers.txt  (array2) using that as an index to do your work.

```
#!/bin/bash
#create array from your find command
files=$(find * -name input)
array1+=($files)
oldnumber="12.345678"

#create array from your numbers file
numbers=$(cat number.txt)
array2+=($numbers)

#create index and iterate through both arrays
for index in ${!array2[*]}; do 
echo "replacing oldnumber $oldnumber with ${array2[$index]} in file ${array1[$index]}"

#searching old number and replacing with new number into the file
newnumber=${array2[$index]}
gsed -i -e "s/$oldnumber/$newnumber/g" ${array1[$index]}


#get the directory of the input file
dirname=$(dirname ${array1[$index]})  

echo "moving ${array1[$index]} to ${array2[$index]}"

#rename the input file
mv ${array1[$index]} $dirname/${array2[$index]}

done
```

This would give you the benefit of having a list of the files to be targeted which could be used for reporting.

**Example: 3 directories:**

```
find * -name input
1/input
2/input
3/input
```

**tree:**

```
├── 1
│   └── input
├── 2
│   └── input
├── 3
│   └── input
```

**numbers.txt:**

```
1.111
2.222
3.333
```

**Script output:**

```
writing number 1.111 into file 1/input
moving 1/input to 1.111
writing number 2.222 into file 2/input
moving 2/input to 2.222
writing number 3.333 into file 3/input
moving 3/input to 3.333
```

**Result:**

**tree:**

```
├── 1
│   └── 1.111
├── 2
│   └── 2.222
├── 3
│   └── 3.333
```

**text within each file:**

```
dir/file:txt

3/3.333:3.333
2/2.222:2.222
1/1.111:1.111
```

Comment: thank you very much.  It will take me a while to digest this but I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Essentially this is using the index [#] to reference both arrays by index value. You'll have much more ability to enhance and develop the script if you extract information the about src/target working components before applying the changes to them. reference  - https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

Comment: That's good to know.  Yes, if I can get this to work, I'm going to be able to use the results to run many simulations that I'll then have to post-process.  I'll need similar code and don't want to keep reinventing the wheel as I have been doing.  I'm working through it now.

Comment: I'm finding that each "input" file is being overwritten by a value in "number.txt" so that a single number from "numbers.txt" is all I'm seeing in each input file.  I will resume this over the weekend and try to figure out where I'm going wrong because like I said, it is bound to be useful for other stuff I need to do.  Thank you again.

Comment: Ah ok. I misunderstood and thought that was the desired result. I have updated the script to search for `oldnumber` and replace with `newnumber` and I have removed `echo ${array2[$index]} >  ${array1[$index]}` which was overwriting whatever was in the file.